# Uncaught ReferenceError: sakla is not defined at HTMLImageElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm getting this error. here below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
        function hide() {
            // some actions
        }
    </script>
</head>    
<body>
    <img id="myImgId" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" onclick="hide()" style="position:absolute;opacity:0.5;left:50%;top:50%;width:50px;height:50px;margin-left:-25px;margin-top:-25px;z-index:100;"/>
</body>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What's in your `hide` function? I suspect the problem is in there.

Comment: Looks like you are accessing something that you not defined in your code.

Comment: function hide(){
  var imgElem = $("#myImgId" );
                console.log("bastın");
                imgElem.css({'display': 'none' })
}

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js" />
    <script>
        function hide() {
            // some actions
        }
    </script>
</head>    
<body>
    <img id="myImgId" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" onclick="hide()" style="position:absolute;opacity:0.5;left:50%;top:50%;width:50px;height:50px;margin-left:-25px;margin-top:-25px;z-index:100;"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys here is the answer but I dont know why should I write the script tag twice. Can someone explain?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        function hide() {
            var imgElem = $("#myImgId" );
            console.log("bastın");
            imgElem.css({'display': 'none' })
        }
    </script>
</head>    
<body>
    <img id="myImgId" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" onclick="hide()" style="position:absolute;opacity:0.5;left:50%;top:50%;width:50px;height:50px;margin-left:-25px;margin-top:-25px;z-index:100;"/>
</body>
```